# Not able to deserialize xml into generic list

Tags: .net, xml, c#-4.0, xmlserializer

I have a following C# classes

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class TransactionTypesHolder
{
    [XmlArrayItem("TransactionType", typeof(TransactionType))]
    public List<TransactionType> TransactionTypes { get; set; }

    public TransactionTypesHolder()
    {
        TransactionTypes = new List<TransactionType>();
    }
}


public class TransactionType
{
    [XmlElement("Mti")]
    public string Mti { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //[XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(Field))]
    //public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Fields")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(Field))]
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class Field
{
    [XmlElement("FieldNumber")]
    public string FieldNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //[XmlArrayItem("FieldPart", typeof(FieldPart))]
    //public List<FieldPart> FieldParts { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "FieldParts")]
    [XmlArrayItem("FieldPart", typeof(FieldPart))]
    public List<FieldPart> FieldParts { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class FieldPart
{
    [XmlElement("PartNumber")]
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("PartValue")]
    public string PartValue { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to deserialize via following code

```
try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new
                    XmlSerializer(typeof(TransactionTypesHolder));

                // A FileStream is needed to read the XML document.
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("Xmlfile1.xml", FileMode.Open);
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);

                // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
                TransactionTypesHolder i;

                // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
                i = (TransactionTypesHolder)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                fs.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
```

But getting error  was not expected.

My xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<TransactionTypes>
  <TransactionType>
    <Mti>200</Mti>
    <Description>Debit</Description>
    <Fields>
      <Field>
        <FieldNumber>3</FieldNumber>
        <Description></Description>
        <FieldParts>
          <FieldPart>
            <PartNumber>
              1
            </PartNumber>
            <PartValue>
              00
            </PartValue>
            <Description></Description>
          </FieldPart>
          <FieldPart>
            <PartNumber>
              2
            </PartNumber>
            <PartValue>
              00
            </PartValue>
            <Description></Description>
          </FieldPart>
        </FieldParts>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <FieldNumber>14</FieldNumber>
        <Description></Description>
        <FieldParts>
          <FieldPart>
            <PartNumber>
              1
            </PartNumber>
            <PartValue>
              9911
            </PartValue>
            <Description></Description>
          </FieldPart>
        </FieldParts>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
  </TransactionType>
  <TransactionType>
    <Mti>100</Mti>
    <Description>Balance</Description>
    <Fields>
      <Field>
        <FieldNumber>3</FieldNumber>
        <Description></Description>
        <FieldParts>
          <FieldPart>
            <PartNumber>
              1
            </PartNumber>
            <PartValue>
              31
            </PartValue>
            <Description></Description>
          </FieldPart>
          <FieldPart>
            <PartNumber>
              2
            </PartNumber>
            <PartValue>
              00
            </PartValue>
            <Description></Description>
          </FieldPart>         
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <FieldNumber>14</FieldNumber>
        <Description></Description>
        <FieldParts>
          <FieldPart>
            <PartNumber>
              1
            </PartNumber>
            <PartValue>
              9911
            </PartValue>
            <Description></Description>
          </FieldPart>
        </FieldParts>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
  </TransactionType>  
</TransactionTypes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following class

```
 [XmlRoot("TransactionTypes")]
    public class TransactionTypes
    {
        [XmlElement("TransactionType")]
        public List<TransactionType> TransactionType { get; set; }
    }
```

instead of TransactionTypesHolder and succesfully able to deserialize the xml

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
    [XmlElement("TransactionTypes")]
    public List<TransactionType> TransactionTypes { get; set; }
```

Try to change to:

```
    [XmlArray(ElementName="TransactionTypes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("TransactionType", typeof(TransactionType))]
    public List<TransactionType> TransactionTypes { get; set; }
```

Also change:

```
    [XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(Field))]
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
```

to:

```
    [XmlArray(ElementName="Fields")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(Field))]
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
```

and the same for:

```
    [XmlArrayItem("FieldPart", typeof(FieldPart))]
    public List<FieldPart> FieldParts { get; set; }
```

to:

```
    [XmlArray(ElementName="FieldParts")]
    [XmlArrayItem("FieldPart", typeof(FieldPart))]
    public List<FieldPart> FieldParts { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have changed it accordingly but got same error <TransactionTypes xmlns=''> was not expected.

Comment: No effect after changing the attribute of Fields  and FieldParts . Infact I have successfully deserialize single TransactionType xml entry to TransactionType object. Problem is only in list filling